# rails navigation and partial refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, frameset, partials

Thanks for your time!

I get some reports data on my hand and I want to present these data on the web. The view of the HTML will be divided into two parts, the left part and the right part. There's a tree view in the left part consisting of the report names. In the right part presents the contents of the report.

What I want to achieve is when I click the report name on the left part, it will call an `Action` in the `Controller`, and passed the report name as parameter. The `Action` will fetch the data from the database and represent the data in the right part. And now I am stuck on how to realize this kind of view.

I've Googled a lot on the Internet and found `Frameset`, `Partials` or `Ajax` may capable of this. Because I've never developed web applications before and also new to Rails. So can anyone give me some advise or suggestion?

Things I've already known :

1. I've used `Frameset` to accomplish a view like this. But I found it needs a lot of `.html` files and all these `.html` files are static. And many people don't suggest it at all.
2. Then I've Googled `Partials`. But it seems `Partials` don't call the Action. It directly loads the `_partials.html.erb` to the main view. And besides, how can I control the layout? Using `CSS`?
3. I've never used `Ajax`.

Comment: This is a really broad question. I think you should check out the
http://www.guides.rubyonrails.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an open question so don't take this answer verbatim, but merely as a guide.

**app/views/layouts/reports.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/">
<head>
   # omitted
</head>
<body>
<div id="body-container">
  <div id="left-column">
    <ul id="reports-list">
      <% for report in @reports %>
        <li><%= link_to report.name, report %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right-column">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app/controllers/reports_controller.rb**

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter { @reports = Report.all }

  def index

  end

  def show
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  def update
   # omitted
  end

  def create
   # omitted
  end

  def destroy
   @report = Report.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
YourApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :reports

  root to: "reports#index"
end
```

This would achieve the effect your after using just rails, of course adding ajax could add a better user experience.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a fluid, seamless transition between one report and another, you should use both AJAX and Partials.

The way that it works is something like:

- Make a left column in the html that has some links
- Make the right column inside a partial
- Assign the links to jQuery listeners to call the AJAX.

I'll put a bit of code here to show how it works:

Controller:

```
def index
    reports = Report.all
    if params[:report_id]
        reports = Report.find(params[:report_id]
    end
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js { render :template => "update_reports" }
    end
end
```

update_reports.js.erb (in the same folder as the report views):

```
$('#report_viewer').html('<%= escape_javascript render :partial => "report_detail" %>');
```

In your view:

```
<div style=float:left>
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Some report", "#", :class => "ajax" %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style=float:right id="report_viewer">
    <%= render :partial => "report_detail" %>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ajax").click(function(e) {
            $(this).ajax("your route to the action");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I think it's basically this, now let me explain a few things:

- I don't remember if you have to do this, but in my case I created a new custom route to force the call to the action to be a json call instead of a html one. You can do this by adding `:format => "js"` to your route
- You must name all your partials like "_yourname.html.erb". Rails won't recognize partials without the leading underscore.
- In the controller, everything that comes after "format.js" is optional, you don't need to specify the template name, and if you don't Rails will look for the file index.js.erb.
- The update_reports.js.erb file is basically a callback javascript that executes to update the current page. It finds the div where the partial is, and updates it rendering a new partial with the new report.
- In the view, the link to change the report don't need to be a link at all if you're using the jQuery.click listener, but if it is a link, it must have the href as "#", or else the browser will just try to redirect to that location.
- There are several ways to hook your link to the ajax function, I just chose the one I like it better, but you also could have a named function and call it in the html tag "onClick='yourFunction()'".
- You need jQuery to call ajax like this. If you're sing Rails 3.0 or lower, you should replace the default Prototype with jQuery, because it's much better (IMHO), but I think prototype also have some ajax features.
- It may seem complicated, but once you get the idea of it it'll become simple as writing any other action.
- In the js callback file you could also add an animation to smooth the transition, like a fading. Look for the jQuery fade function for more info on this.